# Python: how to achieve setinterval function without thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, settimeout, setinterval

I want when a function execute finsish, before the next function execute it could wait some time

and I know the `setinterval` or `settimeout` effect could achieve through `multithreading` or somthing

but I want deploy my app to some `Paas` platform, I am afraid the `thread` is not allowed

Another way I have consider is do some operation which take some time, like:

```
for i in range(30000):
    print i
```

but I'm not sure the `print` could be executed on in the background

So what can I do?

Comment: @zhangyangyu: thank you very much.You can give the comment as your answer, and then I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) can solve your question.